# How to select all id's of all sequences in postgresql?

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using the Django-Framework.
For each model, django generates a relation with a unique id and a squence.

e.g.:

relations: 
myapp__mymodel_a
myapp__mymodel_b
myapp__mymodel_c

sequences: 
myapp__mymodel_a__id_seq
myapp__mymodel_b__id_seq
myapp__mymodel_c__id_seq

Each relation has a unique field "id".
Every id-field has a correspondent squence, amongst others with a field "last_value".

Now I need a SQL command, to get the last_values of all sequences, ending with "_id_seq".

Comment: why do you need the last_value from sequence? you can get the last_value from the table only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t=# do
$$
declare
 _r record;
 _t text;
begin
for _r in (select relname,relnamespace::regnamespace  from pg_class where relname like '%_id_seq') loop
  execute format('select last_value from %I.%I',_r.relnamespace,_r.relname) into _t;
  raise info '%', 'seq: '||_r.relname||', last_value: '||_t;
end loop;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  seq: test_table_id_seq, last_value: 3
INFO:  seq: json_test_id_seq, last_value: 4
INFO:  seq: test_a_id_seq, last_value: 1
INFO:  seq: customer_id_seq, last_value: 4
INFO:  seq: customerstatus_recordid_seq, last_value: 8
INFO:  seq: customerstatus_id_seq, last_value: 1
INFO:  seq: t1_id_seq, last_value: 16
INFO:  seq: s100_serial_id_seq, last_value: 8
INFO:  seq: t2_id_seq, last_value: 4
DO
```

also with coming 10, [there will be](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/catalog-pg-sequence.html) pg_sequence

also `regnamespace` comes with 9.5 for prior version join against `pg_namespace.oid`

Comment: Thx Vao Tsun!
With a simple change, this code works for me.

With your version I got:
`code`ERROR:  42704: type "regnamespace" does not exist
`code`LINE 1: (select relname,relnamespace::regnamespace  from pg_class wh...
`code`                                      ^

For me I removed regnamespace and everything works fine!